# Is there a way to make python showtraceback in jupyter notebooks scrollable?

Tags: python, scroll, jupyter-notebook, styling

Or if there are scrolling functionalities built in, to edit the scrolling settings?

I tried this but it didn't work --

```
def test_exception(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset=None):
    try:
        announce = Announce(etype, value)
        if announce.print:
            announce.title()
            announce.tips()
            announce.resources()
            announce.feedback()
            announce.scroll(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset)
        #self.showtraceback((etype, value, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset)
    except:
        self.showtraceback((etype, value, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset)
    def scroll(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset=None):
        b=widgets.HTML(
        value=self.showtraceback((etype, value, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset),
        placeholder='Some HTML',
        description='Some HTML',
        disabled=True
        )
        a = HBox([b], layout=Layout(height='20px', overflow_y='10px'))
        display(a)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problem. What is it you want to be able to do. see the full output when ever you encounter an error in jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to `cell` > `current outputs` > `toggle scrolling` in the Jupyter UI to enable scrolling output for a cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't seeing enough traceback information, you can always print it directly:

```
import traceback
try: 
    raise Exception('thing')
except:
    TraceBackString = traceback.format_exc()
    print(TraceBackString)
```

produces:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "yourfilehere", line 19, in <module>
>     raise Exception('thing')
> Exception: thing
> ```